# Send a PUT call with JSON data using AJAX and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi i tried to send a PUT request to my slim php api but it seems like that my parameters turns to null.
here is my code:

```js
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'api/edit' + '/' + $('#id').val(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            document.location.href="page.php?update=OK"
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            document.location.href="page.php?update=ERROR"
        }
    });
}

function formToJSON() {
    alert($('#id').val()+' '+$('#param1').val()+' '+$('#param2').val()+' '+$('#param3').val());
    return JSON.stringify({
        "id": $('#id').val(),
        "param1": $('#param1').val(), 
        "param2": $('#param2').val(), 
        "param3": $('#param3').val()
        
}

$('#btnUpdate').click(function() {
        update();
    return false;
});
```

Can someone help me out this? Please.

Comment: its the exact copy paste from your code?? I notice the absence of closing braces for `fromToJSON()` method, make it sure first you don't have any error log in console window of developer tool on for you browser.

Comment: Sorry i foget the closing braces by editing the code here but i do not have error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works with this

```js
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        url: '/api/edit',
        data: {             id: $('#id').val(), 
             param1: $('#param1').val(), 
             param2: $('#param2').val(), 
             param3: $('#param3').val(),
             param4: $('#param4').val()
                            
             } 
        
        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work.

```js
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'api/edit' + '/' + $('#id').val(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            document.location.href="page.php?update=OK"
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            document.location.href="page.php?update=ERROR"
        }
    });
}

function formToJSON() {
    alert($('#id').val()+' '+$('#param1').val()+' '+$('#param2').val()+' '+$('#param3').val());
    return JSON.stringify({
        "id": $('#id').val(),
        "param1": $('#param1').val(), 
        "param2": $('#param2').val(), 
        "param3": $('#param3').val()
        
    })
}


$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnUpdate').click(function() {
        update();
    return false;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: better to write some description, what you have changed, what was wrong etc. so that OP and others can understand the issue, and can easily identify the changes you made.